# How can I place TreeStore data inside of ComboBox

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Question. Please bare me because I am still new with extjs

I am trying to modify the output of an existing (GroupingTree) Tree store to something useful for the simple Combo box drop down because the server side code is not returning data in the dropdown format that I need.

I created a UI Combobox in the code exmple shown below (my function code is commented out)

My store (a Tree store) is coming from a file named GroupingTree.js

but for some reason my function  “getCustomStore” is not getting called so “customStore” is not being returned.

I've been banging my head aginst the wall on this issue. Please help

```
        Ext.define('TV.view.configPanel.data.edit.analyticControls.CustomCaptionNew', {
            extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
            alias: 'widget.customcaptionNew',
            id: 'txtCustomCaption', //TODO: Remove ID - Check with QA

            //Configuration
            isFormattingControl: true,

            /**
            * Initialization of CustomCaption
            * @method initComponent
            */
            initComponent: function () {
                var config = {
                    fieldLabel: 'Custom Caption as Dropdown',
                    blankText: TV.Global.ErrorMessages.CustomCaptionError,
                    name: 'Caption',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    validateOnChange: true,
                    vtype: 'name',
                    minChars: 2,
                    typeAhead: 'true',
                    valueField: 'aggregationCode',
                    name: 'aggregationName',
                    /*store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({fields:['aggregationCode','aggregationName'],
                            data: [['agg1','Cusip'],
                                    ['agg2','ISIN'],
                                    ['agg3','Sedol'],
                                    ['agg4','Group1'],
                                    ['agg5','Security'],
                                ]})*/
                    store: getCustomStore()

                };

                Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
                // Custom validator. For validating the entered caption for analytic.
                Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
                    name: nameValidator,
                    nameText: TV.Global.ErrorMessages.blankText
                });
                this.callParent();
            }
            var getCustomStore = function(){
                    /*var customCaptionStore = {};
                    var fields = ["aggregationName", "aggregationCode"];
                    var data = [{"name","Id"}];
                    //var tempStore = this.getStore(Store.GroupingTreeStore);
                    //alert("Got the proper store");
                    var fields = ['abbr', 'name'];
          var data = [];
          for (var x = 0; x < tempStore.getRootNode().childNodes[1].childNodes.length;  x++){
            data.push({name : tempStore.getRootNode().childNodes[1].childNodes[x].raw.text, abbr: tempStore.getRootNode().childNodes[1].childNodes[x].raw.id});
            }
          var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields:fields,
                data:data
            });
                    customCaptionStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                            fields:fields,
                            data:data
                        });
                    return customCaptionStore;*/
                    alert("Called debug");
                    return new Ext.data.SimpleStore({fields:['aggregationCode','aggregationName'],
                            data: [['agg1','Cusip'],
                                    ['agg2','ISIN'],
                                    ['agg3','Sedol'],
                                    ['agg4','Group1'],
                                    ['agg5','Security']
                                ]});
                };
        });
```

My TreeStore Data

```
            Ext.require('TV.model.AggregationTag');

            Ext.define('TV.store.GroupingTree', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
                filtered: false,

                model: 'TV.model.AggregationTag',
                proxy: {
                    type: 'direct',
                    directFn: ContainerConfigurationData.GetAggregations,
                    paramOrder: ['clientId', 'nodeToLoad', 'searchKey'],
                    paramsAsHash: true
                },
                autoLoad: false,
                treeField: TV.constants.Constant.DataTabFields.GroupingsTreeColumnName,
                //groupField: 'Category',

                root: {
                    expanded: true,
                    loaded: true // Because groupfield is not defined, this is actually required for loading
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function call is not a store object -

```
-->  store: getCustomStore()
```

I would break it out:

define your store first - 
var store = new Myapp.data.TreeStore({
    storeId: 'treeStore',
    autoLoad: 'true',
    model: 'Myapp.TreeModel',

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    actionMethods: {create: 'POST'},
    url: '../include/some_json_block.php',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'nodes',
        idProperty: 'id'
    }
},
root: {
    text: 'Some Root Vx',
    id: '0',
    expanded: true
}
```

});

Then place the store in the panel -- 
var treePanel  = new Myapp.tree.Panel({
    title: 'Panel Tree Manager',
    id: 'mainTreePanel',
    width: 200,
    height: 20,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: true,

Maybe this helps ...